# Find Polynomial given a root with several square root terms of different powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, minimal-polynomials

I have this root and must find a polynomial with all integer coefficients that has this as a root:
$$\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{3}} + \sqrt5$$

I understand that the first step is to set this equal to x and eliminate roots one by one, however for this particular root it gets messy following this simple step. I was wondering what the best way to solve this problem is. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: What have you tried? Where is this problem from? (And the mininal polynomial is of degree $12$, so don't expect a by-hand solution.)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I followed the process of squaring both sides three times, first by moving sqrt5, then twice more, expanding and moving terms each time. My solution only had a polynomial of degree 8. How come it should be degree 12?

Comment: Because I checked with Mathematica. I would expect a deg-$12$ polynomial beforehand because there is a cube root and two square roots, and $2×2×3=12$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Ah yes, that's correct. I mistook the cube root for a square root cubed when I worked out the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Maple:

evala(Norm(z-((2+sqrt(3))^(1/3) + sqrt(5)));

Sort of by hand:
Let $ t = (2 + \sqrt{3})^{1/3} + \sqrt{5}$.

Let's start with $x_1 = 2 + \sqrt{3}$.  This satisfies $(x_1 - 2)^2 = 3$.

Next $x_2 = x_1^{1/3}$.  So $x_1 = x_2^3$, i.e. $(x_2^3 - 2)^2 = 3$, or
$ x_2^6 - 4 x_2^3 + 1 = 0$.

Now $x_3 = \sqrt{5}$, satisfying $x_3^2 = 5$.

The tricky part is $t = x_2 + x_3$.   $x_2$ is an eigenvalue of the companion matrix to the polynomial $x^6 - 4 x^3 + 1$,
$$ A_2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\cr
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
}$$

$x_3$ is an eigenvalue of the companion matrix to its polynomial $x^2-5$:
$$ A_3 = \pmatrix{0 & 5\cr 1 & 0\cr} $$
So $x_2 + x_3$ is an eigenvalue of $$ A_2 \otimes I_2 + I_6 \otimes A_3 =
\pmatrix{0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 
\cr
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\cr
 1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 5 
\cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
}$$
The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is your answer, but I'd hate to do this by hand:
$$z^{12}-30 z^{10}-8 z^{9}+375 z^{8}-2482 z^{6}+1200 z^{5}+9285 z^{4}-8008 z^{3}-16800 z^{2}+14880 z +13876$$